# tvOS collection view cell

Tags: uiimageview, uicollectionview, tvos

I noticed you have to use `.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused` to 'pop' the collection view cell's image when focused. This has created a problem for me, without `.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused` the images are fine, but with that method, it crops my images on the top and bottom.

Did anyone run into this and solve it? I tried `.clipsToBounds = true` but that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Try `clipsToBounds = false` on the cell

Comment: That doesn't work, my images are square but they're still rectangular with clipsToBounds to false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your `UICollectionView` bigger, or use this method to control the focus animation:

```
let originalImageSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100)
let focusedImageSize = CGSizeMake(120, 120)

override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ [unowned self] in
    if self.focused {
        self.imageView.frame.size = focusedImageSize
    }
    else {
        self.imageView.frame.size = originalImageSize
    }
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

You need to add this code to your custom `UICollectionViewCell` class. Hope it helps.

Comment: That did work! How would I go about centering the images so that they get bigger from the center of the image instead of expanding to the bottom right? 

And can I animate that?

Comment: @jbehrens94 You can do something like: `self.imageView.center = self.center` anytime you change the frame of your imageView. Btw, do you mind to accept the answer? :D

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, images are shooting all over my screen.

Comment: Could you share the code shows this strange behavior?

Comment: That happened when I literally set the imageView.center to self.center.